# How to properly reload KDE settings after replacing the kdeglobals file?

Tags: dbus, kde-plasma

I'm making a tool that backs up KDE settings. I want to be able to replace the `kdeglobals` file (normally stored in ~/.config) and reload the settings without restarting the session. Currently, to do this safely, the plasma shell is terminated, then the file is replaced, and finally, a new plasma shell process is started.

I've heard that there is a more proper way to do this using DBus; however, I cannot find the right signal. The answers I've found are outdated and seem to be based on KDE 4 (specifically, they seem point to `org.kde.KGlobalSettings /KGlobalSettings org.kde.KGlobalSettings notifyChange`, but using `qdbus` prints "Cannot find 'org.kde.KGlobalSettings' in object /KGlobalSettings at org.kde.plasmashell"). Is there a proper way to do this in KDE 5, either using DBus or some other mechanism? If not, how does the KCM module achieve this? Can it be done using the shell?

Comment: Looks like calling this function from C could do this:
https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-workspace/-/blob/master/kcms/kcms-common_p.h#L37
Now someone with C knowhow needs to create a little wrapper that only calls this function.